# How to pipelined the Map-input-stream as events directly to WSO2-CEP without selecting or using the "Input mapping type"?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, esper

I am using WSO2-CEP with Esper(as runtime),Esper processed queries on Map as siddhi on tuples."Input Mapping type" basically declares the type of input conversion required for e.g **XML-Mapping**: **XML** to Map or Tuple.I have run an sample by converting xml events to map but what if i have "Map as input events" and i want to process them as Map only? Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 has depreciated Esper (and Drools) in favor of their new Siddhi engine